# Возможно ли интегрировать элементы андроид приложения в страницу открытую в webVeiw?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

Я делаю приложение основанное на webView. И хотелось бы в html страничке которую я открываю вставить элемент приложения. В частности рекламный баннер. Хотелось бы сделать так что бы он не висел постоянно в низу экрана или в другом месте. А пролистывался в месте с содержимым сайта. Рекламу использую от AdMob.

Соответственно как мне кажется было бы правильным это сделать. На сайте мы заранее выделяем блоком с id место в котором должна быть реклама, и после загрузки веб страницы мы внедряем рекламный банер в блок. Но я не уверен, что такое возможно.

Так же есть мысль сразу на html странице оставлять пустое место под рекламный блок. Создавать баннер и постоянно его перемещать по координатам этого блока.

Вторая идея даже для меня звучит очень странно и не понятно, но на всякий случай выскажу вдруг это кого-нибудь натолкнет на верные мысли.

Может ли кто-то подсказать, как я могу осуществить эту задумку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите предельно странного. Короткий ответ - то что вам нужно - нереализуемо.

Длинный ответ будет примерно такой:

1. Нет смысла пытаться встроить реализацию баннера под нативный андроид в HTML, отрендеренный браузером. Если у вас весь контент - в HTML - используйте реализацию баннера для веба. Т.е. как будто бы у вас был просто сайт и андроид тут не при чём.
2. Если вас устроит то, что баннер будет просто внизу экрана, то у вас 2 варианта:

   1. Поместить баннер под `WebView`, указав последней занять всё место, не занятое баннером. Так баннер будет всегда виден на экране.
   2. Обернуть `WebView` и баннер в `LinearLayout`, а его в `ScrollView` - так баннер будет в самом низу контента, после содержимого `WebView`.

---

Ну а вообще - зачем делать приложение полностью на WebView? Почему бы не сделать просто мобильную версию сайта или же нативную версию/нормальную кросплатформу (ReactNative, Xamarin, Flutter)?

Comment: Мобильная версия веб сайта есть. Его я и встраиваю в webView. Что бы он выглядел как приложение, а не сайт. Хотел добавить рекламы именно от AdMob так как слышал, что она более прибыльна, нежели веб реклама. Баннер в низу страницы не очень хотелось делать, так как он постоянно висит у пользователя перед глазами. Не хотелось бы ему этим надоедать. Но видимо придется сделать так. Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @user395494, по идее вам подойдёт вариант 2.2. - пока не промотаешь контент в WebView баннер не появится. Ну и надо иметь в виду, что гугл может не пустить в магазин приложение, построенное на WebView. Точную ссылку на это не нашёл, но вот такая есть про Apple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170598/does-app-store-or-play-store-allow-apps-that-have-a-webview-only-to-my-site